# Tooltip on hover doesnt work

Tags: php, oracle

I am designing a table that retrieved from database and when user hover on of the value in the table, it should gather the corresponding data from the db and show it on tooltip. when i do select query for all value in the table, the tooltip doesnt work. But when I query only 1 particular item in the database it works like a charm. I dont know whats wrong with this. Please help me,

code,

```
$fabSql = "SELECT FABRICATION.*,
                      MASTER_DRAWING.WEIGHT 
                      FROM FABRICATION, MASTER_DRAWING
                      WHERE FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK = MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK";


    $fabParse = oci_parse($conn, $fabSql);

    oci_execute($fabParse);

    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($fabParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) 
    { 
        $totalFabPercentage = (($row['MARKING']*$markingPercentage)+($row['CUTTING']*$cuttingPercentage)+($row['ASSEMBLY']*$assemblyPercentage)+
                               ($row['WELDING']*$weldingPercentage)+($row['DRILLING']*$drillingPercentage)+($row['FINISHING']*$finishingPercentage));

        echo '<tr>';       
            echo '<td>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>';

                if ($row['MARKING'] == 1){
                    echo '<td align="center" title="SIGNED BY : '.$row['MARKING_FAB_SIGN'].' on '.$row['MARKING_FAB_DATE'].'" class="jquery-tooltipped"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok greenyellow"></span>';
                } elseif ($row['MARKING'] == 0) {
                   echo '<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh grey"></span>';
                } else {
                   echo '<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag red"></span>';
                } 

                if ($row['CUTTING'] == 1){
                   echo '<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok greenyellow"></span>';
                } elseif ($row['CUTTING'] == 0) {
                   echo '<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh grey"></span>';
                } else {
                   echo '<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag red"></span>';
                } 
        }
}
```

but when i do query like this, the tooltip works,

```
 $fabSql = "SELECT FABRICATION.*,
                   MASTER_DRAWING.WEIGHT 
                   FROM FABRICATION, MASTER_DRAWING
                   WHERE FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK = MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK
                   AND FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK = 'SMS-MH-BM1'";
```

Comment: have you checked manually whether that query is working or not?

Comment: yes it works manually

Comment: Can you show your javascript side code..?

Comment: @shashank hey thanks for you help but i solved it already :)